# Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone (JS): it exists?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, sdk, windows-phone-8.1, ads

I know that Microsoft advertising SDK for Windows 8(JS) is available, but is there any one for Windows Phone 8/8.1(JS)?

Comment: Do you mean like [this?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-walkthroughs-html5(v=msads.10).aspx)

Comment: Yes, but that's for Windows 8.1, not for Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone.

[image]

Offers:

> Support for JavaScript Render Ready Ads

You can check for updates through VS. I get mine offered automatically.

See here for download:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=8729